# Why does InputStream read method block the resource?

Tags: java, multithreading, randomaccessfile

Why does InputStream's read method block the resource when there's nothing to read?

Let's say I've a RandomAccessFile opened in RW mode, and I create InputStream / OutputStream using File Descriptor.

Thread 1 is trying to read from the file, while nothing is available.
At this time, if thread 2 tries to write to the file, it's blocked.

Why is that so?

Comment: Why don't you try it out for yourself and see? That's known as **research**, and is a great tool for developers to learn.

Comment: I did that. Threads are blocked. I'm trying to understand why'd it block the whole resource ?

Comment: If you already know that it does block, why are you ask *if* it does? If you meant to ask *why*, how come your question is asking *"will it be blocked?"*, instead of *"why is it blocked?"*??

Comment: Updated. My bad. Please help me understand if you know.

Comment: The real question is, why you're creating InputStream / OutputStream from a File Descriptor, rather than creating them independently.

Comment: I want to use an existing connection to the file, rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 Complete nonsense. Servlets and J2EE were envisaged from the start, and there is no non-blocking file I/O in NIO.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `RandomAcessFile` directly to do the I/O? You'll find that is concurrent, where your bodge isn't.

Comment: @user207421 How is RandomAccessFile concurrent? The kernel won't let two systems calls on the same RandomAccessFile execute concurrently. And secondly, even if it did, one RandomAccessFile has only one current file position, so you couldn't do anything useful with two threads at the same time in the same RandomAccessFile.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileDescriptor` is the object carrying the OS file handle, which means it's the object carrying the file pointer.

Only one thread can use the file handle / file pointer at a time, because a `FileDescriptor` does not support multi-threading. Access has been synchronized.

If you want two threads to have independent access to the file, then you need two FileDescriptors.

To prove my point of shared file pointer, what do you think would happen if you alternately read from `FileInputStream` and write to `FileOutputStream`?

Here is code to show what happens:

```
String fileName = "Test.txt";
Files.writeString(Paths.get(fileName), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

try (RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(raFile.getFD());
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(raFile.getFD()) ) {

    byte[] buf = new byte[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int len = in.read(buf);
        System.out.println(new String(buf, 0, len, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

        out.write("1234".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    }
}

String s = Files.readString(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(s);
```

*Output*

```
abcd
ijkl
qrst
abcd1234ijkl1234qrst1234yz
```

As you can see, reading 4 bytes returns bytes 0-3 and moves the file pointer, so writing of 4 bytes replaces bytes 4-7, then reading 4 bytes returns bytes 8-11, and writing of 4 bytes replaces bytes 12-15, and so forth.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you @Andreas.